# How to fix the Routes rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

As my routes the `Sidebar` and the topbar is rendering with `Signup` and login page.

I want to render the `Signup` and login page with a seperate route where the sidebar should not render. And the sidebar and the `Topbar` should render only with the home and other component.

I've used `react-router-dom` for routes and material ui components for the theme.
This is the code:
[image]

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Page1 from "./pages/page1";
import LogIn from './pages/LogIn'
import SignUp  from './pages/SignUp'
import Sidebar from "./scenes/global/Sidebar"
import Topbar from "./scenes/global/Topbar"
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from "./theme";
function App() {
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SignUp/>}/>
          <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn/>}/>
        </Routes>
        <Sidebar isSidebar={isSidebar}/>
        <main className="content">
          <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar}/>
            <Routes>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1/>}/>
            </Routes> 
        </main>
      </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: please copy code as text  instead of picture !

Comment: okay ! what version of react router you're using ?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1"

Comment: I added answer to your question if you find it difficult to implement it write a codesandbox example and I will work on it

Answer (score 0):

you can render the sidebar and the topbar inside each page component.
This will not only solve your problem but will also make it easier for you to manage the project pages.

**for example inside Home.jsx**

```
return (
    <>
        <TopBar />
        <PageContent />
        <SideBar />
    </>
)
```

Comment: Actually, I've added some style to the main "content" class, So I can't add the sidebar onto it. It will affect the sidebar. Can you provide any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using react router v6 you can use [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet#outlet)

Change your **App.js**  like this  :

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<Sidebar  />}>
              <main className="content">
                <Route element={<Topbar  />}>
                  <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
                  <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
                </Route>
              </main>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and in **TopBar.js** :

```
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

    function Topbar() {
       //your code ......
      return (
        <div>
          {Your code goes here } 
          <Outlet/>
        </div>
      )
    }
     
    export default Topbar
```

and in the **Sidebar.js**  :

```
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function Sidebar() {
   // Your code ......
  return (
    <div>
      {Your code goes here}
      <Outlet/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use layouts:**

1. App.jsx

   ```
   <Routes>
        <Route path="/auth" element={<AuthLayout />}>
        //GuestLayout child routes
        </Route>

        <Route path="/home" element={<MainLayout />}>
        //MainLayout child routes 
        </Route>
   </Routes>
   ```
2. MainLayout.jsx

   ```
   <div>
      <Sidebar />
      <TopBar />
      //Render the child routes            
      <Outlet />
   </div>
   ```